# Bin Packing with mutual exclusive items. Goal: Minimum number of bins

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete, dynamic-programming, packing-problem

I am asking for help for the following problem.

- N items. Each Item has to be put into exactly one bin.
- C constraints. Each constraints is a pair of items, meaning item x und item y are not allowed in the same bin.
- There is no limit the the capacity of the bins.
- Goal: Minimum number of bins.

**Background**

The items are exams. And there are students. The exams of **one** student may not be on the same day (= bin), these are the constraints. Each student has approx. 3-10 exams. Goal: Minimum number of exam-days.

**What I did**

If you randomly limit each exam to 2 bins, then this problem can be coded as 2-SAT and be solved in polynomial time.

**Question**

Is there a polynomial time algorithm for this variation of bin packing? May with dynamic programming, because each student has at most 10 exams?

**Edit 1**

While thinking about it, it may be converted to a maximum bipartite matching problem.

Left Nodes: The Exams E1, E2, E3, ....

Right Nodes: The "Exams times bins". E1B1, E1B2, E1B3, .... E2B1, E2B2, ...

Each Exam (e.g. E1) is only connected to its own bins (E1B1, E1B2, ...). This is just a thought. Now we have the problem that the following assigment E1-E1B2 and E2-E2B2 may be forbidden, if E1 and E2 may not be in the same bin (B2).

One could add (left) dummy-nodes connecting exactly two of the right nodes. DummyA to E1B1 and E2B1, DummyB to E1B2 and E2B2, ... . This looked good first, but I think its not working, because the dummy-nodes are to many. They need to have higher priority than the "E to EB" edges, and will "destroy" valid solutions.

Thank you for your help
Benjamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely the question of finding the chromatic number of the graph whose vertex set is N and whose edge set is C.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

It is NP-complete to determine whether 3 bins suffice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do I unterstand it correctly. To transform my problem, I would create a graph and consider VERTEX-COLORING. A VERTEX is an exam and an EDGE connects to vertices if they may not be on the same day (because of a student). And the Question is: What is the minimum number of colors, such that no connected vertices have the same color? Correct?

Comment: "It is NP-complete to determine whether 3 bins suffice." --> Does that mean that 4 bins and more ist also NP-complete?

Comment: @BenBar yes you understand it correctly.  I think that any specific question of the kind you mention ("Is it k-colorable?"  "Is its chromatic number k?"  "What is its chromatic number?") are NP-hard as long as they are not equivalent to "Is it bipartite?" but I am not enough of an expert to know where to find that written down.